# Double-sided a-frame a-panel from Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, aframe

How do I set the material from Javascript for an a-frame a-panel so that the texture become double-sided?

I have managed to do it from outside Javascript with 
`<a-plane src="image.jpg" material="side: double">` but I cannot get it to work with Javascript.

This is a non-working example where only the front is visible:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function setup() {
       scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');

       var entity = document.createElement('a-entity');
       entity.setAttribute('position', '0 1.6 -1');

       var plane = document.createElement('a-plane');
       var planeMaterial = document.createElement('material');
       planeMaterial.setAttribute('side', 'double');
       plane.appendChild(planeMaterial);
       plane.setAttribute('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Jubilee_and_Munin%2C_Ravens%2C_Tower_of_London_2016-04-30.jpg/240px-Jubilee_and_Munin%2C_Ravens%2C_Tower_of_London_2016-04-30.jpg')
       entity.appendChild(plane);

       scene.appendChild(entity);
     }
     window.onload = setup;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene></a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the html you provided, this is what you need.

`plane.setAttribute('material','side:double');`

The code you have posted generates

`<a-plane src="image.jpg"><material side="double"></material></a-plane>`

---

```js
function setup() {
  scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');

  var entity = document.createElement('a-entity');
  entity.setAttribute('position', '0 1.6 -1');

  var plane = document.createElement('a-plane');
  plane.setAttribute('material', 'side: double;');
  plane.setAttribute('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Jubilee_and_Munin%2C_Ravens%2C_Tower_of_London_2016-04-30.jpg/240px-Jubilee_and_Munin%2C_Ravens%2C_Tower_of_London_2016-04-30.jpg')
  entity.appendChild(plane);

  scene.appendChild(entity);
}
window.onload = setup;
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene></a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I find that this works. I did try `plane.setAttribute('material', 'side: double;');` before and it didn't work, but have now updated to your suggestion of version 0.7.0 and that version works.